# How to create new database upon reopening application?

Tags: c#, database, logging

I have a log viewing application that writes log statements to a database and then sends them from the database to the log viewer GUI.  I want to be able to open more than one instance of the log viewer but when I do it will be creating a database with the same name as the previous instance of the viewer.  I've tried creating a database with a different name if one has already been created but that doesn't seem to work.  Any suggestions?  Here's the code for creating/accessing/destroying databases:

```
public class Database
{

    public bool hasAdminPriv
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool hasBeenCreated
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Database()
    {
        hasAdminPriv = true;
        //Construction checks to see if user has Admin priveleges
        bool isElevated;
        WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
        isElevated = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
        if (!isElevated)
            hasAdminPriv = false;
    }

    //returns true if the database creation was successful
    public bool CreateDatabase()//creates a database dynamically by making a query request to the server
    {
        String str;
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + Environment.UserName + "-D1SD\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Master;Integrated Security=True");

        str = "CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase ON PRIMARY " +
        "(NAME = MyDatabase_Data, " +
        "FILENAME = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL.1\\MSSQL\\Data\\MyDatabaseData.mdf', " +
        "SIZE = 30MB, MAXSIZE = 10GB, FILEGROWTH = 20%) " +
        "LOG ON (NAME = MyDatabase_Log, " +
        "FILENAME = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL.1\\MSSQL\\Data\\MyDatabaseLog.ldf', " +
        "SIZE = 10MB, " +
        "MAXSIZE = 1GB, " +
        "FILEGROWTH = 10%)";

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
        try
        {
            myConn.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            int done = 0;
            while (done < 10)
            {
                String str2 = "CREATE DATABASE" + done + " MyDatabase ON PRIMARY " +
                                "(NAME = MyDatabase_Data, " +
                                "FILENAME = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL.1\\MSSQL\\Data\\MyDatabaseData.mdf', " +
                                "SIZE = 30MB, MAXSIZE = 10GB, FILEGROWTH = 20%) " +
                                "LOG ON (NAME = MyDatabase_Log, " +
                                "FILENAME = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL.1\\MSSQL\\Data\\MyDatabaseLog.ldf', " +
                                "SIZE = 10MB, " +
                                "MAXSIZE = 1GB, " +
                                "FILEGROWTH = 10%)";
                SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(str2, myConn);
                try{
                    myCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch{
                    ++done; 
                }
                myConn.Close();
                hasBeenCreated = true;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                myConn.Close();
            }
        }
        hasBeenCreated = true;
        return true;
    }

    //Creates the table in the database by a query request
    //a return value of true means Database was created succesfully
    public bool CreateTable()
    {
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + Environment.UserName + "-D1SD\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True");
        string createString = "CREATE TABLE storage (ID INT NOT NULL, Level varchar(255) , LevelInt INT, DateTime varchar(255),Counter smallint,Device varchar(255), Source varchar(255), Description varchar(255),PRIMARY KEY (ID))"; //YOUR SQL COMMAND TO CREATE A TABLE
        SqlCommand create = new SqlCommand(createString, myConn);
        myConn.Open();
        create.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConn.Close();
        return true;
    }

    //Add the element's values to the database/table to later recall/reorder
    public bool addElement(LogParse log,int num)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + Environment.UserName + "-D1SD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True");
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into storage(ID, Level, LevelInt, DateTime, Counter, Device, Source, Description) values(" + num + ",@Level, @LevelInt, @DataTimeItem,@counterItem,@deviceItem,@sourceItem,@descItem)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Level", log.Level);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LevelInt", log.LevelInt);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataTimeItem", log.TimeStamp);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@counterItem", log.SequentialNumber);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deviceItem", log.Device);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sourceItem", log.Source);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descItem", log.Description);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    //outputs a string array with all the values in the database
    public LogParse[] readValue(int start, int end)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + Environment.UserName + "-D1SD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        LogParse[] s = new LogParse[end - start];
        try
        {
            using (var oCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * From storage WHERE ID BETWEEN @Start AND @End", con))
            {
                oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start", start);
                oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@End", end);
                using (var oReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    while (oReader.Read() && i < end-start)
                    {
                        //s[i] = oReader.GetString(1) + oReader.GetString(2) + oReader.GetString(3);
                        String Level = oReader.GetString(1);
                        Int32 LevelInt = oReader.GetInt32(2);
                        String Datetime = oReader.GetString(3);
                        Int16 SequentialNumber = (Int16)oReader.GetValue(4);
                        String Device = oReader.GetString(5);
                        String Source = oReader.GetString(6);
                        String Description = oReader.GetString(7);

                        s[i] = new LogParse();
                        s[i].Level = Level;
                        s[i].LevelInt = LevelInt;
                        s[i].TimeStamp = DateTime.Parse(Datetime);
                        s[i].SequentialNumber = SequentialNumber;
                        s[i].Device = Device;
                        s[i].Description = Description;
                        s[i].Source = Source;
                        ++i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        con.Close();
        return s;
    }

    //Deletes the database by a query statement
    //a return value of true means the delete was succesful
    public static bool deleteDatabase()
    {
        String str;
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + Environment.UserName + "-D1SD\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Master;Integrated Security=True");
        str = @"ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;DROP DATABASE [MyDatabase]";
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
        try
        {
            myConn.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                myConn.Close();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... why do you need different instances of the same database just for multiple log viewers? What if you have a team of 10 people using your application... there would be 10 different databases, all of which are separate and unsynced? What if you had a team of 100 users? Maybe I'm misunderstanding your application's intent, but I must agree with Malachi, this doesn't sound safe and efficient at all. I would suggest making all instances of the log viewer to read/write from the same database.

Answer (score 3):

**DON'T** create another database, or table, it's evil. Just add Instance ID into table `storage`. And when writing new logs just add instance ID, same goes when reading from DB, put instance ID into where clause.

Another issue is to pick good Instance ID, your scenario is not very clear to me, but if you want every new application instance to have separate data, just create new GUID and use it as Instance ID.

For example you can have static property InstanceID in your Database class, and your class could look something like this :

```
public class Database
{
    public static Guid InstanceID = new Guid();

    //Add the element's values to the database/table to later recall/reorder
    public bool addElement(LogParse log,int num)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + Environment.UserName + "-D1SD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True");
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into storage(ID, InstanceID, Level, LevelInt, DateTime, Counter, Device, Source, Description) values(" + num + ",@Level, @LevelInt, @DataTimeItem,@counterItem,@deviceItem,@sourceItem,@descItem)", con);
            // writing InstanceID
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InstanceID", Database.InstanceID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Level", log.Level);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LevelInt", log.LevelInt);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataTimeItem", log.TimeStamp);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@counterItem", log.SequentialNumber);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deviceItem", log.Device);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sourceItem", log.Source);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descItem", log.Description);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    //outputs a string array with all the values in the database
    public LogParse[] readValue(int start, int end)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + Environment.UserName + "-D1SD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        LogParse[] s = new LogParse[end - start];
        try
        {
            // select with InstanceID
            using (var oCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * From storage WHERE InstanceID = @InsID ID BETWEEN @Start AND @End", con))
            {
                oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start", start);
                oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@End", end);
                oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InsID", Database.InstanceID);
                using (var oReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    while (oReader.Read() && i < end-start)
                    {
                        //s[i] = oReader.GetString(1) + oReader.GetString(2) + oReader.GetString(3);
                        String Level = oReader.GetString(1);
                        Int32 LevelInt = oReader.GetInt32(2);
                        String Datetime = oReader.GetString(3);
                        Int16 SequentialNumber = (Int16)oReader.GetValue(4);
                        String Device = oReader.GetString(5);
                        String Source = oReader.GetString(6);
                        String Description = oReader.GetString(7);

                        s[i] = new LogParse();
                        s[i].Level = Level;
                        s[i].LevelInt = LevelInt;
                        s[i].TimeStamp = DateTime.Parse(Datetime);
                        s[i].SequentialNumber = SequentialNumber;
                        s[i].Device = Device;
                        s[i].Description = Description;
                        s[i].Source = Source;
                        ++i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        con.Close();
        return s;
    }
}
```

btw. **DON'T** swallow exceptions ! I leave your code the same but please don't do that, it's also evil, another thing is if there is a exception in your addElement method your connection will not be closed, use [Using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

that doesn't sound safe at all,  maybe one database with several user tables to store the logfiles for each user, but this just doesn't sound right to me.

otherwise a variable that is assigned randomly when the application is started in place of the database name when it is created.

but if you do something wrong there are going to be a lot of databases out there, but it looks like you have figured out sizing and some other things to keep them from overpowering the server machine.

**Additional Information from Comment**

if you are going to use tables on the Database(which I think is what you really need) then create the database separate and then create randomly named tables inside your application every time it is opened, you may want to have another table that would keep track of the the tables and the times they were opened as well, perhaps even what user opened them and such things like that

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  In this case should I create the database outside of the code for my application as opposed to creating a new database each time the application is opened?

Comment: if you are going to use tables on the Database(which I think is what you really need) then create the database separate and then create randomly named tables inside your application every time it is opened, you may want to have another table that would keep track of the the tables and the times they were opened as well, perhaps even what user opened them and such things like that.